# Debezium Connector for RDS Aurora

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-aurora, debezium

I'm trying to use debezium with rds/aurora/ and I'm thinking which connector to use MySQL connector or there is another connector for Aurora? Also, how can i connect debezium connector(localhost) to remote aws aurora db? Also, is someone using debezium with aurora to share some info.

Also, how can i configure debezium to write into different kafka topics the different tables which we are monitoring?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

While creating AWS Aurora instance you must have chosen between

- Amazon Aurora with MySQL compatibility
- Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL compatibility

Based on this you can choose between MySQL or Postgres connector for Debezium. There is no separate connector for Aurora.

> how can i connect debezium connector(localhost) to remote aws aurora db?

You need to configure connector with `database.hostname` and `database.port`

Refer - https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/index.html